# Setting that $α >1$, calculate $\sum_{j=[nα]}^{n[α+1]}\frac{1}{j}$, when $n$ goes to $\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $α > 1$. Calculate the limit of summation of $1/j$ from $j=[nα]$ to $n[α+1]$, when $n$ goes to $\infty$, i.e.
$$\sum_{j=[nα]}^{n[α+1]}\frac{1}{j}.$$

Comment: What does sigma mean?

Comment: it should be summation Σ

Comment: Thank you, I guessed that.

Answer (score 1):

We prove a more general result: Let $k_n \le l_n$ with $l_n,k_n \rightarrow \infty$ for $n \rightarrow$ and $l_n/k_n \rightarrow \beta$. (Of course, $\beta \ge 1$). Comparing with the corresponding integral (note that $x \mapsto 1/x$ is monotone), we have on the one hand
$$\sum_{j=k_n}^{l_n} \frac{1}{j} \ge \int_{k_n}^{l_n+1} \frac{1}{x} \, d x= \ln \Big( \frac{l_n+1}{k_n}\Big) \rightarrow \ln \beta.$$
On the other hand, the same argument shows that
$$\sum_{j=k_n}^{l_n} \frac{1}{j} \le \int_{k_n-1}^{l_n} \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \ln \Big( \frac{l_n}{k_n-1} \Big) \rightarrow \ln \beta.$$
Thus, the limes is $\ln \beta$. In the special case $l_n = n \lfloor \alpha +1 \rfloor$ and $k_n = \lfloor \alpha n \rfloor$, we have $l_n /k_n \rightarrow \lfloor \alpha +1 \rfloor / \alpha$ and therefore
$$\sum_{j= \lfloor n \alpha \rfloor}^{n \lfloor \alpha +1 \rfloor} \frac{1}{j} \rightarrow \ln \Big( \frac{\lfloor \alpha+1 \rfloor}{\alpha} \Big).$$